# Why won't my form add a new item to the list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a new item to a list. However, for some reason neither my prevent default function nor my function that adds items to a list is working. The code is below

```
import React from "react";
import "./list.css";

class List extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        list: ["Dark Night", "Whiplash", "Inception", "Moonlight", "Gladiator", "SpiderMan", "Batman", "Hulk", "Avengers", "Normal People", "Inbetweeners"]
      }
    }

addItem(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const {list} = this.state;
  const newItem = 'test';

  this.setState({
    list: [...this.state.list, newItem]
  })
}

render(){
  const {list} = this.state;
    return(
      <div className='list'>
      {
        list.map(item => {
          return <p key={item}>{item}</p>
        })
      }
      <form>
        <div className='form-group' onSubmit={(e) => {this.addItem(e)}}>
        <label className='sr-only' htmlFor='newItemInput'> </label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Whats to cool" id='newItemInput' />
          <button type="submit" className="listButton">Add</button>
        </div>

      </form>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

export default List;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onSubmit` should be used with `form` tag

but you have used it with `div` so in that case `e.preventDefault();` what it will prevent :)

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {this.addItem(e)}}>
```

---

**Working code snippet :**

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        list: ["Dark Night", "Whiplash", "Inception", "Moonlight", "Gladiator", "SpiderMan", "Batman", "Hulk", "Avengers", "Normal People", "Inbetweeners"]
      }
    }

  addItem(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const {list} = this.state;
    const newItem = 'test';

    this.setState({
      list: [...this.state.list, newItem]
    })
  }

  render(){
    const {list} = this.state;
      return(
        <div className='list'>
        {
          list.map(item => {
            return <p key={item}>{item}</p>
          })
        }
        <form  onSubmit={(e) => {this.addItem(e)}}>
          <div className='form-group'>
          <label className='sr-only' htmlFor='newItemInput'> </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Whats to cool" id='newItemInput' />
            <button type="submit" className="listButton">Add</button>
          </div>

        </form>
        </div>
        );
    }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code below:**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./list.css";

class List extends Component{
    state = {
        list: ["Dark Night", "Whiplash", "Inception", "Moonlight", "Gladiator", 
               "SpiderMan", "Batman", "Hulk", "Avengers", "Normal People", 
               "Inbetweeners"]
      }
    }

addItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const {list} = this.state;
  const newItem = 'test';

  this.setState({
    list: [...this.state.list, newItem]
  })
}

render(){
  const {list} = this.state;
    return(
      <div className='list'>
      {
        list.map(item => {
          return <p key={item}>{item}</p>
        })
      }
      <form onSubmit={e => this.addItem(e)}>
        <div className='form-group'>
        <label className='sr-only' htmlFor='newItemInput'> </label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Whats to cool" id='newItemInput' />
          <button type="submit" className="listButton">Add</button>
        </div>

      </form>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

export default List;
```

Comment: What does your code do differently? You should always try to give an explanation instead of a code-only answer.